# Ogre Error In Cmake

Tags: cmake

While implementing CMake in my code I am getting an ogre error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOGRE
```

My CMakeLists.txt file looks like:

```
#Specify the version being used aswell as the language
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

#Name your project here
project(eCAD)

#sets cmake to run moc when needed
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

#find requirements of this projects
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
find_package(Qt5Core) 
find_package(OGRE)
find_package(OIS)
# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

#Sends the -std=c++11 flag to the gcc compiler
add_definitions(-std=c++11)

qt5_wrap_ui(Cmake_form_hdr resources/ui/mainwindow.ui)

#This tells CMake to main.cpp and name it eCAD
add_executable(eCAD main.cpp  ${Cmake_form_hdr})

#include the subdirectory containing our libs
add_subdirectory (gui)
include_directories(gui)

#link_libraries
target_link_libraries(eCAD Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Core OGRE OIS)
```

I am new to this. Please help me out to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

The command `find_package(OGRE)` runs file `FindOGRE.cmake` and sets variables `OGRE_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `OGRE_LIBRARIES`. To link with the `OGRE` library, you should use these variables, e.g.

`target_include_directories(eCAD PRIVATE ${OGRE_INCLUDE_DIRS})`
`target_link_libraries(eCAD ${OGRE_LIBRARIES})`

This is same for all of the external libraries you use.

Comment: What gives you `MESSAGE(${OGRE_LIBRARIES})` ?

Comment: Using this got an error : message called with incorrect number of arguments

Comment: Please open and read file `FindOGRE.cmake`. There is written that you can set the environment variable `OGRE_HOME`.

Comment: I am unable to locate FindOGRE.cmake file. Can you please help me out.